# Create a hosting plan service with WebSiteManagementClient.WebHostingPlans.Create and got error "Request to a downlevel service failed"

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm using WebSiteManagementClient.WebHostingPlans.Create to create a hosting plan. Everything was working fine last week, but now I got this error: `Request to a downlevel service failed`. Has someone had this problem as well and knows how to fix it?

```cs
 var credentials = CertificationAuthenticationHelper.GetCredentials(args.SubscriptionId, args.Certification);
 WebSiteManagementClient webSiteManagement = new WebSiteManagementClient(credentials);
 WebHostingPlanCreateParameters param = new WebHostingPlanCreateParameters();
 param.Name = FormatNameHelper.AzureWebsiteName(args.Message.WebsiteName);
 var resService = webSiteManagement.WebHostingPlans.Create(ConfigurationHelper.WebSpaceName, param);
```